# d3.js catch the nearest line with mouse click

Tags: d3.js, line, draw

I need to draw a line which start with another line's nearest point considered to my left-click. I use d3.js library for drawings. For example, I want to draw a big 'T' letter and need to match those cross-point automatically. I can draw every kind of lines and other structures just want to put together.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share some of your code, I don't understand what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I draw lines like that and want to connect points like this link. http://postimg.org/image/z97d7oecf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example could help you to draw lines.To draw lines continuously just click on page and move the mouse. if you want to stop drawing lines just double-click ever you like.
If still there is a problem share your code or update your question.

```
var line;

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
      .attr("width", 600)
      .attr("height", 400)
      .on("click", mousedown)
      .on("dblclick", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
       var m = d3.mouse(this);
       line = vis.append("line")
       .attr("x1", m[0])
       .attr("y1", m[1])
       .attr("x2", m[0])
       .attr("y2", m[1]);

    vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
  }

 function mousemove() {
            var m = d3.mouse(this);
            line.attr("x2", m[0])
            .attr("y2", m[1]);
   }

  function mouseup() {
         vis.on("mousemove", null);
  }
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/7cqaeu7n/1/).

Comment: I can draw lines for now. But my problem is, I need to catch another line with my mouse click to start another line with starting last's lines some position.

http://imgur.com/Gz34oAq

I need to draw this red lines with touching the main drawing with using mouse click. I hope I explain myself.